# Ruby: Create hash with default keys + values of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I believe this has been asked/answered before in a slightly different context, and I've seen answers to some examples somewhat similar to this - but nothing seems to exactly fit.

I have an array of email addresses:

```
@emails = ["test@test.com", "test2@test2.com"]
```

I want to create a hash out of this array, but it must look like this:

```
input_data = {:id => "#{id}", :session => "#{session}", 
              :newPropValues => [{:key => "OWNER_EMAILS", :value => "test@test.com"} , 
                                 {:key => "OWNER_EMAILS", :value => "test2@test2.com"}]
```

I think the `Array` of `Hash` inside of the hash is throwing me off. But I've played around with `inject`, `update`, `merge`, `collect`, `map` and have had no luck generating this type of *dynamic* hash that needs to be created based on how many entries in the `@emails` Array.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to pull this off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So basically your question is like this:

having this array:

```
emails = ["test@test.com", "test2@test2.com", ....]
```

You want an array of hashes like this:

```
output = [{:key => "OWNER_EMAILS", :value => "test@test.com"},{:key => "OWNER_EMAILS", :value => "test2@test2.com"}, ...]
```

One solution would be:

```
emails.inject([]){|result,email| result << {:key => "OWNER_EMAILS", :value => email} }
```

**Update:** of course we can do it this way:

```
emails.map {|email| {:key => "OWNER_EMAILS", :value => email} }
```

Comment: inject is definitely the best solution

Comment: Ah ha! so that is how I would inject! This helps me a lot .. It not only solves my problem, but makes me understand inject a bit better. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed inject or map_reduce in other languages is a cool way to iterate a collection + apply some operation on all it's elements and moving the partial result to successor elements while iterating.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's wrong with `emails.map {|email| {:key => "OWNER_EMAILS", :value => email} }`?

Comment: @sepp2k you are a real Guru ;), using #map will work of course, but I wanted to show other use of inject :D Thanks!

Comment: Of course, and I played around with #map for awhile - I was over-complicating the solution that's for sure.